# resource injection in ejb

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I don't understand the difference between `lookup` parameter and `name` parameter of the `@Resource` annotation. I read all the documentation about the annotation and its field etc.

I know how `name` can be used to inject or bind a resource, but the problem is that did not find any example that explain the difference between `lookup` and `name`.

Can anyone give me a such example or tell me the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is a "virtual" reference name in the `java:comp/env` namespace.  At some level, that reference needs to point to a "physical" resource that has been defined.  The standard way to do that is with the `lookup` attribute, but products will also have a way to "bind" the the resource reference, so in many products, the product-specific binding is functionally equivalent to the name.  (The product-specific binding is still important because you don't want to rely on developers to hard-code data source names from the operational environment, etc.)

For example, you might have `@Reference(name="jdbc/myDS", lookup="jdbc/oracleDS")`, which means `java:comp/env/myDS` will be defined as an indirect lookup to the `jdbc/oracleDS` data source that was bound to the default JNDI namespace.

For another example, you might have `@DataSourceDefinition(name="derbyDS")` and `@Resource(name="jdbc/myDS", lookup="java:comp/env/derbyDS")`.  The former defines an actual data source (again relative to `java:comp`), and the latter defines an indirect lookup to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "par"? Which specific piece is unclear?

Comment: Sorry I don't mean anything by "par", I added it unconsciously, the point which is not clear is the difference between them and when to use one over the other ?

Comment: You use `name` when you want to give a name to your resource ref.  You use `lookup` to define what the resource ref should be bound to.